# Complexity classes for various models of computation

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-models

The various complexity classes usually taught and studied ($P$, $NP$ $co-NP$, EXP, NSPACE etc) are usually defined using Turing Machines as the preferred model of computation.

Are these sets of decision problems (complexity classes) independent of the model of computation used?

Comment: It depends on the model of computation... but many of these classes are quite robust.